# Why is React state not changing simultaneously with input change for a controlled component

Tags: reactjs

I don't think I missed anything in making the form a controlled component. Why doesn't the state doesn't change as characters are being input?

```
class AddChores extends Component {
  state = {
    chore: "",
  };

  handleChange = (evt) => {
    this.setState({ chore: evt.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    this.props.addChores(this.state);
    this.setState({ chore: "" });
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div>
        <form onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="New Chore"
            value={this.state.chore}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <button className="button">ADD CHORE</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}[![React dev tool showing no simultaneous update][1]][1]
```

Comment: does event have to be passed here onChange={this.handleChange} ?

Comment: you need to initialize the state in a constructor I think: constructor = () => {this.state={chore: ""}}

Comment: Have you checked your console for any error messages?

Comment: I tried passing evt object. I tried the full constructor form of constructor(props){super(props};this.state={chore:''}}. I tried this.setState(() =>({chore:evt.target.value})). I tried this.setState({chore:evt.target.value}, () => console.log(this.state)). I tried several combinations of the above. Nothing works so far. Strange.

Comment: No error on console

Comment: Can you clarify what you think should be a simultaneous update? I see only a single state update.

Comment: Copied your code into a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-is-react-state-not-changing-simultaneously-with-input-change-for-a-controlle-rmcd0) it appears to function as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes as below and it works fine for me. Hope it helps you too.

```
 class AddChores extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chore: ""
    };
   
  }

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      chore: event.target.value
    });
    
  };

  handleSubmit = (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // this.props.addChores(this.state);
    this.setState({ chore: "" });
  };
  
  componentDidUpdate(){
    console.log('the state', this.state.chore)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="New Chore"
            value={this.state.chore}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </form>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your suggestion and replaced my code with it. Still doesn't work. It has to be something outside of what was in that component. Killed the server and restarted. Still doesn't work. I have no idea. First time I have had this issue. Thank you everyone for the help nonetheless.

Comment: I noticed that on console it does now show the state change without the methods being bound in constructor. It's the dev tool not showing it. Not sure if it's a bug or what. Thanks Saba for the suggestion of explicitly logging it on console. I was focusing more on dev tool.

Comment: `handleChange` and `handleSubmit` are arrow functions, so `this` is already bound to them. You also shouldn't do side-effects like console logging in the render function, it can result in odd and indeterminate behavior.

Comment: If you try to log the state *within* the same render cycle as the enqueued state update it will log the current state, not the state to be updated. You can use either the `setState` callback or better, a lifecycle method like `componentDidUpdate` to log the updated state. Also, other than moving the log and removal of the external call to `this.props. addChores` how is this different than OP's code?

Answer (score 0):

not sure why is this happening but try using the second form of `setState`
`this.setState(() => ({ chore: evt.target.value}))`
check this https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous